# Display filtered data onSubmit/click

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to filter the results in a inputbox from a form when user/s submit or click the submit button in Angular 12, but i cannot make the pipe to work in the component and so not in the view.

HTML

```
                       <form #form="ngForm" >
                          <div class="form--inline clearfix d-flex">
                             <div class="form-item">
                                <label for="edit-combine">Buscador de Informes</label>
                                <div class="inner-addon left-addon" style="position: relative">
                                   <i class="bi bi-search" style="position: absolute; padding: 5px; pointer-events: none; font-size: 1rem"></i>
                                   <input style="padding-left: 30px" placeholder="Buscar" type="text" id="edit-combine" name="combine" value="" size="30" maxlength="128" class="form-text form-control" [(ngModel)]="titleList">
                                </div>
                             </div>
                             <div id="edit-actions">
                                <input type="submit" class="button" (click)="onSubmit()" id="edit-submit-buscador-de-informes" value="">
                             </div>
                             <div *ngFor="let flex of informesTitle">
                                {{flex}}
                              </div>
                          </div>
                       </form>
```

TS Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { FlexSlider, FrontService, InformesCounter } from './front.service';

import { FrontPipe } from './front.pipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-front',
  templateUrl: './front.component.html',
  providers: [ FrontService, FrontPipe ],
  styleUrls: ['./front.component.sass']
})
export class FrontComponent implements OnInit {
  error: any;
  flexImage: FlexSlider[] | undefined;
  flexTitle: FlexSlider[] | undefined;
  informesCount: InformesCounter | undefined;
  informesTitle: InformesCounter[] | any;
  titleList: InformesCounter[] | any;
  frontPipe: FrontPipe[] | any;
  filteredText: InformesCounter[] | any;

  constructor(private frontService: FrontService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.showData();
    this.showInformes();
  }

  showInformes() {
    this.frontService.getInformes()
      .subscribe((data: InformesCounter) => {
        this.informesCount = data.meta;
        this.informesTitle = data.data;
        this.titleList = this.informesTitle.map((data: { attributes: { titulo: any; }; }) => data.attributes.titulo);
        this.filteredText = new FrontPipe().transform(this.titleList);
        
      });  
  }

  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.filteredText)
  }
```

TS PIPE

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'front'
})
export class FrontPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any): any {
    if (!items) {
      return items;
    }

    return items.filter(function(data: string){
      return data.toLowerCase();
    });
    
  }
  
}
```

So i cannot make the Pipe to work inside a component who receive JSON Data from a service to filter the results. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Forgot to pass the Pipe args to the function and put them into the onSubmit Function.

```
onSubmit(){
this.filteredText = new FrontPipe().transform(this.titleList, this.searchText);
console.log(this.filteredText)
}
```